# Efficient property setting within Python class

Tags: python

I have a class which queries a database for it properties.  As you can see in the code below, I need to set a `candidates` property, but then set a `prime` property based on the `candidates` property.  However, I want to avoid querying the database twice.  What's the best way to go about this?

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def candidates(self):
        # get candidates from db
        return query_result

    @property
    def prime(self):
        # get prime based on complex logic with candidates.  Simplified eg:
        return self.candidates[0]  # hits db again :(
```

If I set `self.prime` within the `candidates` definition but then call `prime` before `candidates`, I will get an error.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache the result in a private variable.

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._candidates = None

    @property
    def candidates(self):
        # get candidates from db
        self._candidates = query_result
        return query_result

    @property
    def prime(self):
        # get prime based on complex logic with candidates.  Simplified eg:
        return self._candidates[0]
```

This assumes you want to hit the database / refresh the data each time the `candidates` property is accessed. If the candidates property is not so dynamic, then you can front-end the query. Like so:

```
    @property
    def candidates(self):
        if self._candidates is None:
            # get candidates from db
            self._candidates = query_result
        return self._candidates
```